# Input data for indexer

Tags: c#

I have class with method remove, it needs to delete Customer from CustomerList.

```
    public class ObservableList<T>
    {
        List <T> CustomerList = new List<T>();
        public void Remove(ObservableList<Customer> list) // not correct 
        {
            //something for delete from list;
        }
    }
```

indexer in this class:

```
    public T this[int indexer]
    {
        get { return CustomerList[indexer]; }
        set { CustomerList.Add(value); }
    }
```

The string for testing this method looks like this:

```
ObservableList<Customer> list = new ObservableList<Customer>();
LoadFromBin(list, "source1.bin");

list.Remove(list[2]);
```

The question is, how to properly format the input data for this method(Remove)? And is the indexer executed correctly in my code?

Comment: Can you please explain why do you have generic wrapper around list of concrete type? What is the point of `T` in `ObservableList<T>`? How this should work for example is user will create `ObservableList<decimal>`?

Comment: There are enough issues with this code that I'd first recommend seeing if existing collections won't serve your needs better than trying to write your own. Notably, `ObservableCollection` is already a thing.

Comment: Also can you please explain the "not correct" comment? What is not correct? Why is it not correct?

Comment: @GuruStron not correct input in parentheses of the method. I think I've fixed an answer and it must look clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the attempted usage `Remove` should accept `T`, not a collection:

```cs
public class ObservableList<T>
{
    List <T> CustomerList = new List<T>();
    public void Remove(T toRemove) => CustomerList.Remove(toRemove);
}
```

But again, based on usage it seems you should consider implementing `RemoveAt`:

```cs
public class ObservableList<T>
{
    List <T> CustomerList = new List<T>();
    public void Remove(T toRemove) => CustomerList.Remove(toRemove);
    // usage: list.RemoveAt(2);
    public void RemoveAt(int index) => CustomerList.RemoveAt(index); 
}
```

As for the indexer - it is covered in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/), your `set` method should set value for index, not add element:

```
public T this[int indexer]
{
    get { return CustomerList[indexer]; }
    set { CustomerList[indexer] = value; }
}
```

But in general, unless it is some exercise you are doing - consider advice from [@Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) in the comments - see if existing collections won't serve your needs better than trying to write your own.